# CardLayout panel display error in existing frame

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, cardlayout

I have designed a frame containing a few controls using the design view in Netbeans 6.9.1. Further, I have added an empty panel in which I am trying to toggle display of a couple of swing components on button click. The problem is that on button click, the panel displays nothing. The code is as follows:

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    JPanel txtPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel listPanel = new JPanel();

    JTextField txtfield = new JTextField("ABCDEFGHIJ", 20);
    txtPanel.add(txtfield);

    JList<String> list = new JList<String>();
    DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < userCommands.size(); i++){
        model.addElement(userCommands.get(i));
    }
    list.setModel(model);
    listPanel.add(list);

    jPanel2.add(listPanel, "list");
    jPanel2.add(txtPanel, "text");

    //MainUI.getFrames()[0].add(jPanel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    itemStateChanged("text");
}
```

Code for `itemStateChanged` is as follows:

```
    public void itemStateChanged(String disp) {
    CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(jPanel2.getLayout());
    cl.show(jPanel2, disp);
}
```

In the first piece of code, `jPanel2` is dragged and dropped onto the frame containing other components, what i am trying to achieve here is that on button click, the `jPanel2` should toggle between text field and list. But currently, the panel is not displaying anything on button click.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Before even considering if jPanel2 can switch between the different panels (the different cards), is jPanel2 on display at all anywhere? The only code I can see that displayes the jPanel2 is adding it to the MainUI but it is commented out?! So how do you know that the display inside jPanel2 isn't switching?

Comment: as I mentioned, the jPanel2 has been dragged-dropped to to MainUI, i commented this piece of code out because since it is dragged-dropped, there is no need to re-add it to MainUI frame...I think it is not switching because the area of JPanel2 is as is when I press the button...nothing happens, it neither displays the textfield nor the jlist...any ideas?

Comment: I dont have much experience in dragging and dropping a JFrame and not sure how this affects the rest of your application. When the JFrame is dropped onto the MainUI is the MainUI displying the correct JPanel?

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick example code for you .Have a look.You need to define the Card layout as global and try.

```
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
```

public class TestPanel extends JPanel {

```
/**
 * Create the panel.
 */
JPanel panel;
CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
public TestPanel() {
    GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 155, 0, 0};
    gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{94, 0, 0};
    gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    setLayout(gridBagLayout);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnNewButton = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnNewButton.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_btnNewButton.gridx = 0;
    gbc_btnNewButton.gridy = 0;
    add(btnNewButton, gbc_btnNewButton);
    btnNewButton.setAction(new AbstractAction("New button") {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            JPanel txtPanel = new JPanel();
            JPanel listPanel = new JPanel();

            JTextField txtfield = new JTextField("ABCDEFGHIJ", 20);
            txtPanel.add(txtfield);

            JList<String> list = new JList<String>();
            DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                model.addElement("Sanjaya");
            }
            list.setModel(model);
            listPanel.add(list);

            panel.add(listPanel, "list");
            panel.add(txtPanel, "text");

            //MainUI.getFrames()[0].add(jPanel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            itemStateChanged("list");

        }
    });

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_textArea = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_textArea.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_textArea.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_textArea.gridx = 1;
    gbc_textArea.gridy = 0;
    add(textArea, gbc_textArea);

    panel = new JPanel(cl);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_panel = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_panel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_panel.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_panel.gridx = 2;
    gbc_panel.gridy = 0;
    add(panel, gbc_panel);

}
  public void itemStateChanged(String disp) {


        cl.show(panel, disp);
    }
```

}

Comment: also try creating jPanel2  as JPanel jPanel2=new JPanel(cl);